# My map iterator is not working to access each element of the map, how do I fix it?

Tags: c++, string, dictionary, insert, iterator

I need to insert every element of my map (both the first and second of each pair element) in to a string. Every solution I've looked up does something similar to this:

```
for(map<string, int>::iterator iter = theMap.begin(); iter != theMap.end(); ++iter)
{
  myString.insert(iter->first);
  myString.insert(iter->first);
}
```

I keep getting an error saying `no matching function for call to 'std::basic_string<char>::insert(const std::basic_string<char>&)'`

How do I output every element of a map? Especially in string's!

Comment: Do you want to append it to `myString`?

Comment: Yes, I want to add both elements (the key and value) of each pair of the map onto myString.

Comment: Then you'll want to use `append`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append.

Comment: If you really think you can't access the elements of a map with an iterator, then test that, and not some string insertion.

Answer (score 3):

Use `stringstream` to do this for a general `map` with keys and values overloading `operator<<`.

```
stringstream makeMyString;
for(map<string, int>::iterator iter = theMap.begin(); iter != theMap.end(); ++iter)
{
  makeMyString << iter->first << " " <<iter->second;
}
string myString = makeMyString.str();
```

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is telling you what is wrong. There is no matching function call, `insert` is usually `insert(position, string)`.

So you cen either do the following:

```
stringstream stringmaker;
stringmaker << iter->first << iter->second; //You need to do this to convert your
                                            // int key into a string.

myString.insert(myString.size(), stringmaker.str())
```

or better

```
myString.append(stringmaker.str());
```

Answer (score 1):

"no matching function for call to 'std::basic_string::insert(const std::basic_string&)'" - very true - see [insert docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert).

You could use append as Yuushi commented; if you want to append `iter->second` you'll first need to convert it to a `std::string`, perhaps with `boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(iter->second)`, or using `std::ostringstream oss; oss << iter->second; myString.append(oss.str());`.

Alternatively, you can use streaming, in which case the most flexible approach is to first write a function that outputs the `std::map` to a `std::ostream`, then apply that to a `std::ostringstream`, then call `.str()` to get a `std::string` version:

```
void output_iterator_over_pairs(std::ostream& os, Iterator begin, Iterator end,
                                const char* between_pairs = ", ",
                                const char* inside_pairs = ":')
{
    for (bool first = true; begin != end; ++begin)
    {
        if (first) first = false; else os << between_pairs;
        os << begin->first << inside_pairs << begin->end;
    }
}
```

Then you can do something like:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
output_iterator_over_pairs(oss, theMap.begin(), theMap.end());
// use oss.str()...
```

You could actually overload `operator<<(std::ostream&, const std::map<T, U>&)` but if two parts of the code have the same brilliant idea it can get messy... marginally harder to vary the separator strings used too, though you could add your own iomanipulators with a little work (much like [`std::fill()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill)).